# Naming spec for WMI counters

Tags: naming-conventions, wmi, standards, specifications

Is there a specification for parsing the names of WMI performance counters?  Standard names look like '\Xxxx\Yy yy\Zzzz zzz', but we are seeing some custom names that look like '\Aaaa aaa \Bb bb BLAH(bbb\bbbb)\Ccc ccc ccc', i.e., trailing spaces, and embedded parenthetical elements with embedded '\'s.  Is there a spec that describes what is allowable in these names?

Here are some typical standard counter names:

```
\Process(Idle)\% Processor Time
\Process(System)\% Processor Time
\LogicalDisk(HarddiskVolume1)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Transfer
\LogicalDisk(C:)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Transfer
\LogicalDisk(_Total)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Transfer
\LogicalDisk(HarddiskVolume1)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Read
\LogicalDisk(C:)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Read
\LogicalDisk(_Total)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Read
\LogicalDisk(HarddiskVolume1)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Write
\Thread(w3wp/7)\Priority Current
\Thread(w3wp/8)\Priority Current
\Thread(explorer/7)\Priority Current
\MSMQ Outgoing HTTP Session(*)\Outgoing HTTP Bytes
\MSMQ Queue(os:zyxwvut1dv\private$\profilestats_submissions_dev_current_1)\Messages in Queue
\Per Processor Network Interface Card Activity(1, Intel(R) PRO-1000 MT Network Connection)\Received Packets/sec
\Netlogon(\\ZY2XWVUT1.app5000.online)\Semaphore Waiters
```

Here are some custom counter names:

```
\Customer App (current) DEV(netmix\auth.asmx\authtkts)\ErrorCode.InvalidState Count
\Customer App (current) DEV(lorem\ipsem.asmx\rdunlcks)\ErrorCode.InvalidState Count
\Customer App (current) DEV(netmix\legal.asmx\getvalidverid)\ErrorCode.OutOfRange Count
\Customer App (current) DEV(lorem\acq.asmx\submit)\ErrorCode.OutOfRange Count
\Customer App (current) DEV(netmix\milestones.asmx\getmilestones)\ErrorCode.OutOfRange Count
\Customer App (current) AUTH(*)\ErrorCode.UnknownError Count
```

**Note:**
I am *not* looking for just a regex that will match the given strings above. I would like to have the reference to the documented spec that defines this.

Comment: Please write exact example of the names you mean, so we will understand about which naming you are talking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names are of the form \A\B

1. A has a limit of 256 characters
2. B has a limit of 1024 characters
3. It does not appear that there are any particular 'invalid' characters for either.

References (check the 'name' subsection of each) :

- A: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- B: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Well this is a bummer. So I can't unambiguously separate the parts from a name if either one has an embedded '\'. There is no way to tell a delimiting '\' from a content '\'. :(

Comment: @Paul That's what it looks like. The good news is that \A\B is a constructed name, so you may be able to get at the data in a different fashion. How are you getting the names right now?

Comment: @Jon - Using remote registry access with Samba (on Linux).

Comment: @Paul - Tricky, but it looks like you can get the information you are looking for. There's some examples on msdn. In particular, this one seems to do what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Paul - Happy to help. Don't forget that you have to manually award the bounty if you're happy with the answer.

Comment: @Jon - -1 for SO UX points. If I've put a bounty on something, and I accept the answer, I would assume the bounty would be awarded to the answerer. Thanks for the reminder. (This is my first bounty)